# a-video, a-image (with video as source) not visible in VR mode in Windows Mixed Reality - Aframe 0.8.2

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am using:

- Aframe 0.8.2
- Edge 41.16299, EdgeHTML 16.16299
- Windows 10

Code https://pastebin.com/98DUNfBz

Problem: When I enter in VR mode in HMD in Windows Mixed Reality, video entity (`a-video`) and image entity (`a-image`) (with video as source) disappears. They are visible in non-VR mode before entering VR mode.
If I enter in VR mode without HMD (of Windows Mixed Reality) i.e. normal VR mode in desktop all those entities are visible.
I am getting the same problem with Aframe versions `0.7.1` and `0.8.0`. There is a slight change: those entities appear as black rectangles (in VR mode with HMD in Windows Mixed Reality)
Please let me a work around of this problem. Thanks
(if I am missing any information please let me know)

**update**: I am getting this error console continuously.

```
WEBGL11156: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: The data for this video is not available three.js (19378,1)
WEBGL11098: drawArrays: The texture is a non-power-of-two texture or not mipmap complete
```